# If the set $\{v_1, v_2, v_3\}$ is linearly independent, then so is the set...

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

If the set $\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ as a subset of $\mathbf R^n$ (doesn't have to be in $\mathbf R^n$) is linearly independent, then so is the set $\{2v_1 + v_2 +v_3 , v_1 + 2v_2 + v_3 , v_1 + v_2 + 2v_3\}$. Give a proof if true, or a counterexample if false.

Comment: What do you think? What work have you done on this problem?

Comment: I am not sure, but I was thrown off by the fact that it said the set {v1,v2,v3} are a subset of R^n, and not in R^n. What difference does this make? @LarryB.

Comment: Doesn't make a difference; it's a set of vectors, and that set is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, which means each vector is in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Do you see how $\{2v_1+v_2+v_3,v_1+2v_2+v_3,v_1+v_2+2v_3\}$ relates to the matrix $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}2&1&1\\1&2&1\\1&1&2 \end{smallmatrix}\right]$?  Do you know how the reduced row echelon form relates to the linear independence or dependence of a set of vectors?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

By the definition of [linear independence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_independence#Definition), you have to prove that
$$
1)\qquad a(2v_1+v_2+v_3)+b(v_1+2v_2+v_3)+c(v_1+v_2+2v_3)=0
$$
iff $a=b=c=0$

reordering $1)$ we have:
$$
v_1(2a+b+c)+v_2(a+2b+c)+v_3(a+b+2c)=0
$$
and, if $\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ are linearly independent this is equivalent to:
$$
\begin{cases}
2a+b+c=0\\
a+2b+c=0\\
a+b+2c=0
\end{cases}
$$

Now solve the system.